# Adding a method for existing type in Golang: how to rewrite return value's type

Tags: go

I want to extend existing [goquery.Selection](http://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection) type with my own method and be able to use it from package's selectors. I know that I cannot "patch" existing method -- I need to create a new one. But how do I can force the existing package functions to use my new type? Something I'm missing in general or there's no "nice" way to do it and it's better to use a function?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

type customSelection goquery.Selection

func (s *customSelection) CustomMethod() int {
    return 1
}

doc.Find("*").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
  fmt.Println(s.CustomMethod())  // does not works since its still "goquery.Selection"
  // how do I can get a result with customSelection type here? 
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since inheritance is not supported, the best practice is to embed the non-local type into your own local type, and extend it.

In the Design Patterns lingo its better known as composition:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: *aaaaaand* either provide a new type with a new `Find` that returns a new kind of collection, and `Each` on that new kind of collection to call its callback with a `customSelection`, or else just make a constructor to wrap a `Selection` in a `customSelection`, which is easier if you're not writing a whole framework.

Comment: So basically I should modify each existing method that I want to return a new type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use function instead of method:

```
func customFunc(s *goquery.Selection) int {
    return 1
}

...

fmt.Println(customFunc(s))
```

Comment: Yeah, I have mentioned in the question that I can easily use function, but I'm looking for a way to make it more nice and use method.

Comment: Why a method is nicer than a function?

Comment: A method allows you to add interface conformance to a struct.

Comment: @theory, however it doesn't make a method "nicer" and interface conformance was not part of the question. If methods are always "nicer" than functions then there is no reason to have functions ;)